# Fade in div doesn't fade, but is already there

Tags: jquery, function, fadein, fade, fadeout

I made this easy jQuery script, but I have a little problem. 
After i fade my first div out my second fadeIn doesn't work, because the div is already there... I already tried to slow down the fadeIn with more milliseconds, but it didn't work. This is my script.

```
$("#nothing > h1").click(function(){
$(this).fadeOut(1000);
$("#social").fadeIn(1000);  
  });
```

And this is my HTML

```
<div id="nothing">
    <h1>Click here.</h1>
</div>

<div id="social">      
   <h2>Nothing to see here</h2>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: provide you html mark up please

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsFiddle I made for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/LJK3P/1/

```
$('#social').hide();

 $("#nothing > h1").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();// Just in case

     //You probally would want to fade out the parent of the h1 so add parent() 
     $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000, function() { 
         $("#social").fadeIn(1000);
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is supposed to happen sequentially, you must call the `fadeIn()` inside the callback of the `fadeOut` event, like this :

```
$("#nothing > h1").click(function(){
   $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
     $("#social").fadeIn(1000);
   });    
});
```

Hope this helps!